# Google Pub/Sub for Web UI Update?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to the GCP and currently have a microservice architecture using GKE and gRPC. The microservices are publishing events to Google Cloud Pub/Sub. My Web-UI is
using Google Cloud Endpoints to send requests to the Microservices. 
I want to have a lot of live/push updates on the website (such as live updating user statistics etc) and now wonder how this is done best. Is it a bad practice to let the Web-UI subscribe to a topic in Google Cloud Pub/Sub? Are there other technologies in the GCP that may be better for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub is intended for `torrents` use cases, where you have a lot of data communicated between relatively few publishers/subscribers.

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) might better fit the particular `trickles` use case you describe, where you are sending smaller updates to many, possibly transient, subscribers.

Comment: Would it be okay to use **Cloud Functions** to receive pub/sub events end send them to a client via **Firebase Cloud Messaging** (Thanks for the good answer btw I was looking at Firebase as a Google Cloud Messaging replacement).

Comment: Yes, this would be a typical use case.  Cloud functions can be triggered on pubsub messages and forward them on to firebase cloud messaging (formerly known as Google Cloud Messaging).  If you're looking to transition from Google Cloud Messaging, the transition doc is [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).